# I want to average the top N in a list, when one row begins with a specific text

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a list of football players, and in front of their names is their position.  In the next column, I have their projected fantasy football statistics. I'm trying to average only the top five, based on the position they play.

For Example: What is the average projection of the top 5 "RB's".

Link below for an example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QLwXM1K_kbYLdABpaKFNbZ2p8UYRSSHKl-dbB_Ytdnk/view?usp=sharing

I can do Averageif function, but I'm having trouble only choosing the top 5 players.

I've also tried this formula, but it's returning an error. I think I'm messing up the variable.

=SUMPRODUCT(LARGE((A2:A="RB"&"*")*(B2:B),{1,2,3,4,5,}))

Answer (score 2):

Try...

```
=AVERAGE(LARGE(IF(LEFT(A2:A23,2)="RB",B2:B23),{1,2,3,4,5}))
```

..which needs to be confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER.

Comment: I'm inclined to think this is the right answer to the question ' I'm trying to average only the top five'

Comment: Having re-read the question (and just noticed the 'Excel' tag) I agree - I've modified my answer accordingly to account for a QUERY-based approach if the OP is actually using Google Sheets.

Answer (score 2):

A more compact QUERY-based answer can be obtained using the *starts with* operator for the *where* clause:

```
=average(query(A2:B,"select B where A starts with 'RB' limit 5",0))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `QUERY()` function. Try-

```
=QUERY(HSTACK(CHOOSECOLS(INDEX(SPLIT(A2:A," ")),1),A2:A,B2:B),
"select Col2,avg(Col3) 
where Col1='RB' 
group by Col2 
order by avg(Col3) DESC
limit 5
label avg(Col3) ''",0)
```

[image]